# Adding multiple attributes values applies only the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery

Adding multiple attributes values applies only the first one, wondering why is this happening code below:

```
jQuery("#gform_submit_button_1").attr({
  style: "color: #fefefe !important",
  style: "background-color: #000000 !important"

});
```

If i change their places it still applies which one is the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them into one attribute:

```
jQuery("#gform_submit_button_1").attr({
  style: "color: #fefefe !important; background-color: #000000 !important"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Stating 2 different `style` tags causes the seconds one to override the first one. If you want to change multiple style properties, either pass them in the same `style` tag, or you can use JQuery `.css` rather than `style`:

```
jQuery("#gform_submit_button_1").css({
  "color":, "#fefefe !important",
  "background-color": "#000000 !important"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats how objects work. They are not allowed to have two values for one key:

```
console.log({
  style: "color: #fefefe !important",
  style: "background-color: #000000 !important"
});
```

So you may join them together, which can be automated:

```
var styles=["color: #fefefe !important","background-color: #000000 !important"];

jQuery("#gform_submit_button_1").attr({
 style:styles.join(";")    
});
```